# How to split a NSAttributedString by width?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring

I have a given view-width size (e.g. 450, which I got from `viewWidth = rectOftable.size.width;` ) where rectOftable is rectangle with size(width & height) of a content view. Now, I created an NSAttributedString which contains a string, which may have a size greater than 450 ( e.g. 1100 ).

What I need to do is split this NSAttributedString into multiple substrings with respect to a given width (450 here, which is the size of the view ). So, here 1100/450 = 2+1 lines I need to display.

Currently, what I can do is split the NSAttributedString only by length, i.e. `[attrStr attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, 170)]`  where 170 here is currently the length, but size is 1100.

How do I instead split the NSAttributedString by width? There is no reference anywhere regarding this.

Comment: Welcome to [SO].  You might want to [format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question a bit to make it more readable.  People are less incline to help when they have to spend a lot of time trying to read/understand a question poorly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's done using a NSTextContainer (such as [NSTextView textContainer]):

```
// remember the orginal values
BOOL widthTracksTextView = [textContainer widthTracksTextView];
BOOL heightTracksTextView = [textContainer heightTracksTextView];
NSSize containerSize = [textContainer containerSize];
CGFloat lineFragmentPadding = [textContainer lineFragmentPadding];

// set these as we need them
[textContainer setWidthTracksTextView:NO];
[textContainer setHeightTracksTextView:NO];
[textContainer setContainerSize:screenFrame.size];
[textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0.0];

// this cause glyph generation and layout
(void) [textView.layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];

// return the size that the view would need to be in order to display
// all the glyphs that are currently laid into the container
NSRect layoutRect = [textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
layoutRect.size.width = ceil(layoutRect.size.width);
layoutRect.size.height = ceil(layoutRect.size.height);

// restore orginal values
[textContainer setContainerSize:containerSize];
[textContainer setWidthTracksTextView:widthTracksTextView];
[textContainer setHeightTracksTextView:heightTracksTextView];
[textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:lineFragmentPadding];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a complex problem; what can fit in a given space depends on the font, the font size, and other factors, all of which may vary over the length of your `NSAttributedString`. This is why OS X provides classes to handle all; see `NSTextView`, `NSText`, `NSLayoutManager`, etc.

Do you really need to break the text yourself? If not then use the classes provided. If yes then you've some reading to do!